# Is there a method to get Changed Contacts Names instead of Cached Names in CallLogs in android programming

Tags: android, android-contacts, telephonymanager

I am developing an app to get CallLogs. From CallLogs i get Cached Name of the person calling. Now if i change the name of the person in the contact List. it is not reflected in CallLogs. How to handle it

Answer (score 0):

The [`CallLog.Calls`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls) table contains fields for caching names, because these are cached names, they're not expected to always be true, and are refreshed from time to time.

Most Phone/Call-log apps will display the calls list along with their cached names stored in the `Calls` table, and then spin-up a background thread to refresh those cached names columns - adding names to numbers recently saved as contacts, or updating names that had recently changed.

So if you've updated a contact's name, and then launch the call-log app you should see the updated name appearing within a second or two.

If you want to update the cached name programatically in your code, you can do that easily:

```
String someNumber = "+12125551234"; // this is format-sensitive, so it must be exactly as it appears in the call-log
String aName = "Jane Addams";

final ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
values.put(Calls.CACHED_NAME, aName);

// on Lollipop+ device, you can also set Calls.CACHED_LOOKUP_URI and Calls.CACHED_FORMATTED_NUMBER

getContentResolver().update(Calls.CONTENT_URI, values, Calls.NUMBER + "='" + someNumber + "'", null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. But how do i get the updated name ?? . Getting information from Contract.contact will make it inefficient , if i have to check every entry of CallLog in Contract.Contacts

Comment: There's no other option then getting the info from ContactsContract APIs, but you don't have to have one query per call-log entry, you can do it in batches of ~50 phones in one go, by using selection like `Phone.NUMBER IN (1111, 2222, 3333)` that should be fairly efficient